# Custom one-click deployment

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I really like the one-click deployment feature of cloudbees jenkins and would like to use it for my own deployments.

Since i'm not running on run@cloud, is it possible to configure a shell script as a way of deployment or implement a custom plugin to hook into this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my own jobs that do the deployment. The easiest deploy jobs just call a shell script. Works as a charm and the jobs do everything I need. I can start them from a another job. They are super flexible since I can add as many parameters as I want for the deployment. The only shortcoming is, that I don't have that nifty looking link but I can life without it.

Comment: using a second job is indeed a very good solution. you can do great thing with the promoted build plugin this way. this question is really only about getting that nifty looking link.

Comment: May be you can try the batch task plugin. Have a look at it. However, chances are that this is a special cloudbees plugin, that you only get when using their infrastructure.

Comment: how do you pass input parameters to the deploy job? (which branch to deploy, where etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tools that you are usign, for example in my case I use sbt and I think you can add a task on sbt to deploy to a non cloudbees server.